# Setting selected item of a select element using async pipes in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, async-pipe

Angular experts! I'm trying to understand async pipes in Angular, but I'm stuck in a basic scenario. I have two select elements in the UI, one containing posts and one containing related comments. I want to set a posting (the last one) as the initially selected one for the select element displaying posts, and I want to use the selected item to filter related comments in the second select. This is not working in my code, for which I have created a simplified version in Stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p6ynuy

Can any of you explain to me what I'm doing wrong? This is the relevant code fragment and HTML:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.postList$ = this.getPostList();

    // latestPost$ is not is use yet, but maybe it could be used to set the selected post?
    this.latestPost$ = this.postList$ 
      .pipe(
        map(posts => posts[posts.length - 1])
      );

    this.selectedPost$ = combineLatest([
      this.postList$,
      this.postSelectedAction$
    ])
      .pipe(
        map(([posts, selectedPostId]) => posts.find(post => post.id === selectedPostId))
      );

    this.commentList$ = this.selectedPost$
      .pipe(switchMap(
        post => this.getCommentList(post)
      ));
  }


<select [ngModel]="selectedPost$ | async" (change)="onSelected($event.target.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let post of postList$ | async" [ngValue]="post">
    {{post.id}} {{post.title}}
  </option>
</select>
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let comment of commentList$ | async" [ngValue]="comment">
    {{comment.id}} {{comment.postId}} {{comment.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Angular Compares Objects by Reference by Default**

You are almost there. The problem is that your `select` gets a list of `option`s referencing `Post`s as part of `ngFor`. Now to find out which `option` is currently selected, Angular compares each `post` object with the current value of `selectedPost$ | async`.

The way that's done is, by default, using the `===` operator. The `===` operator compares primitives by value, but objects by reference. Example:

```js
console.log('a' === 'a');
const obj = {'a': 'b'};
const obj2 = obj;
console.log(obj === obj2);
console.log(obj === {'a': 'b'});
```

So in order for `post` to count as the same post as `selectedPost$ | async`, they'd have to be the actual same object, not just an object that looks the same.

**You Actually Retrieve Multiple Copies of The Same Post, Not Just one Post**

Now that's not the case: As you're using the `async` pipe, it can happen that during change detection, posts are reloaded from the API. When you check out your browser's network tab, you can actually see that there are three requests:

[image]

The response payload of all requests is the same, but as the `Post` objects are returned three times, they are stored in memory three times. JavaScript has no way of knowing they are actually the same, and the `===` comparison returns `false`.

**Solution: Provide Your Own `compareWith` function**

How can you solve this? You can help Angular compare `Post` objects properly in your `select`. You just have to ask yourself the question: How do I know that two `Post` objects are in fact the same object? The answer, in this case, is: When they have the same ID.

You can now write your own instruction for Angular to compare objects or your select: Just add a `compareWith` input to the select:

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedPost$ | async" 
(change)="onSelected($event.target.value)"
[compareWith]="comparePosts"
>
```

Now Angular knows to use a method called `comparePosts` to compare two posts. Now how can that method look? For example like this:

```
comparePosts(p1: Post, p2: Post) {
    return p1.id === p2.id;
}
```

Now Angular knows how to properly compare two `Post` objects and your problem is solved.

PS: Please make sure to write a better `comparePosts` method than I did, for example also properly handling `undefined` and `null` values.

Comment: Thanks fjc, It worked perfectly and I learned something new! Could I ask if you are able to spot why the second select (comments) is not updated when I select a post in the first select?

Comment: You're welcome. As far as I can see, the comment select is not updated because you nowhere wired it up with any value. For your post select, you have an ngModel set. For your comment select, there's no such thing.

Comment: You are right, and I am planning to add an ngModel to get the selected comment, but for now I just want the list of comments to be filtered by the selected post. Which I am trying to do with a switchMap, as you can see on line 38. I guess that is not the way to do it. Would you have a better suggestion?

Comment: I found the bug myself. I expected the wrong input parameter in onSelected. Thanks again for your invaluable help!

Comment: Nice, I'm glad you did. I didn't get the chance to check it out yet. You're very welcome, it's nice to see a well written, clear question with an actually reproducible problem for a change.